# Raspberry suddenly stoped booting

Tags: boot-issues

I wanted to try my Raspberry Pi 4 B with (I think) 8GB.

When I first plugged it in as I found it it seemed to work before getting to the rainbow screen and turning of.

After that there was no sign of life ever since. I tried to re-flash the OS with Raspberry Pi Imager (SD Card Boot, USB Boot, Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32-bit), Raspberry Pi OS Full (32-bit), Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit), Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)).

The power LED lights up but act doesn't. There is no visible damage and I don't remember dropping/scratching it. There never was any smoke or large overheating.

Is there any hope or is it ready for the trash?

All help is appreciated <3

Comment: What spec power supply?

Answer (score 0):

Work through the comprehensive [boot problems sticky](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151).

If that doesn't help your Pi is dead.

Answer (score 0):

If the ACT LED doesn't blink quickly in an irregular pattern for at least twenty seconds, this indicates that the Pi cannot read from the SD card, and that booting is not taking place.

So the conclusion is that your SD card have died!